# prove: $\mathrm|{A}|=|\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N^{\mathrm{+}}}}\mathrm{A}^{n}|$ when $\mathrm{|A|\geq|A\times A|}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $$\mathrm{|A|\geq|A\times A|}$$ as $A$ is a given set such that $|A| > 1$.

For every $n\geq1$, let $\mathrm{A^{n}}$ be the set of function from $\{0,1,....,n-1\}$ to $\mathrm{A}$.

> prove: $$\mathrm|{A}|=|\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N^{\mathrm{+}}}}\mathrm{A}^{n}|$$

if we look on any object: $\mathrm{A^{i}}\in\mathrm{A^{n}}$ as $i\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathrm{A^{i}}=\mathrm{A^{n}}$ , than any $\mathrm{A^{i}}:i\longrightarrow\mathrm{A}$  as I understand is defined to be onto, therefore $\mathrm{A^{n}}$ is onto $A$, so $$|\mathrm{A}|\leq|\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N^{\mathrm{+}}}}\mathrm{A}^{n}|$$
(this is just some ideas I had because I didn't really found any information about how to solve this type of Q).

after that, it is clear that I'll need to use the fact $\mathrm{|A|\geq|A\times A|}$ in some way so I could use CBS, but i really can't find the way to solve this.

Comment: You also need $A $ to be infinite (singletons are a counterexample).

Comment: Hint: the given inequality is $|A^2|\le|A|$, which implies $|A^n|\le|A|$ for all $n$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo is it allowed to say: 
given $|A|\geq|A\times A|$, 

suppose $|A|\geq|A^{n}|$.

prove: $|A|\geq|A^{n+1}|$

$A^{n+1}=A^{n}\times A$ and since $|A|\geq|A\times A|$ and by the induction hypothesis, we'll get that $|A|\geq|A^{n+1}| $?

Comment: @Jneven That is obvious. The difficulty of the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo i managed to prove that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}^{+};\ |A| \geq |A^n|$. 

I'd want to prove the other direction, that there exists an inversiable function $f:A \to \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb {N}^{+}} A^n$, and i'm not sure how.

Comment: Again, what you proved is obvious. You still need to address the difficult part of the problem.

Comment: which is exactly the part the confuses me - therefore I'm still working on this question. notice i edited the question, as the book was updated after I posted the question.
so $|A| > 1$ and specifically; $|A| \geq \aleph_{0}$ as $|A\times \mathbb{N}| \leq |A\times A| \leq |A|$

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, let us suppose that $A$ is neither a singleton nor empty, so that it has to be infinite (it is trivial for the empty set and false for a singleton).

The inequality $|A| \leq |\bigcup A^n|$ can be seen even easier by noting that there is a trivial bijection between $A$ and $A^1$.
Next, note that $A^n$ can be identified with the $n$-fold cartesian product $\underbrace{A \times \dots \times A}_{n \text{ times}}$, in particular, $A^{n+1} = A^n \times A$.
Using the hypothesis, you can show by induction that $|A| = |A^n|$ for every $n \geq 1$. Now we construct an injection $f \colon \bigcup A^n \rightarrow A$. Let me first explain what we want to do. Imagine $A$ as a square in the plane. Then we will embedd $A^1$ in one half of the square, embedd $A^2$ in one half of the half, i.e. a quarter, of the square, embedd $A^3$ in one eigth of the square and so on. There probably are quicker proofs but mine is explicit.

Consider the sets $A^n$ as subsets of $A^{n+1}$ simply by embedding them via $(a_1,\dots,a_n) \mapsto (a_1,\dots,a_n,x)$ for some fixed element $x \in A$.
Since $|A| = |A^2|$, there is a bijection $f_2 \colon A_2 \rightarrow A$.
Given an element in $a \in A^1$ define $f(a)$ to be $f_2(a)$. This way, $f$ maps $A_1$ onto the set $f_2(A^1)$. Convince yourself that $A \setminus f_2(A^1)$ still has the same cardinality as $A$ since we have $|A| = |A^2|$.
Thus, $|A \setminus f_2(A^1)| = |A| = |A^3|$ and there is a bijection $f_3 \colon A^3 \rightarrow A \setminus f_2(A^1)$. Given $a \in A^2 \subset A^3$ define $f(a) = f_3(a)$.
As before, $A \setminus (f_2(A^1) \cup f_3(A^2))$ still has the same cardinality as $A$ and we can proceed this procedure indefinitely.

Comment: so just to make sure - the induction you prove by constructing the different injection, or is there other ways to prove it?

Comment: I understand the idea of the proof but I'm confused about how to "formal" it

Comment: The induction is just $|A| \geq |A \times A| \geq |A^n \times A| = |A^{n+1}|$, where the second inequality is the induction hypothesis for $n$. What exactly is unclear? I agree that it is a little vague to say "we can do this procedure indefinitely", but I personally would count it as a valid proof.

Comment: could you explain how to did you come up with proving that for every $\ n, \ |A| = |A^n|$ ?

Comment: I've read you answer for many times and I still can't figure how to organise it and formal it.